# Multivariable derivatives of two functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Problem 2. Let the pressure $p$ and temperature $T$ at a point $(x,y,z)$ be $$P(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2+2y^2}{1+z^2},\quad T(x,y,z)=5+xy-z^2$$
>
> a. If the position of an airplane at time $t$ is $$(x(t),y(t),z(t))=\left(2t,t^2-1,\cos t\right)$$ find $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(PT)^2$ at time $t=0$ as observed from the airplane.

Could anyone could walk me through this or even give me some pointers on how to start/proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula for total derivative:
$$ \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was confused about whether I would have to actually calculate (PT)^2 first, or if there's a simpler way to go about it?